# Business days between two dates in objective-c?

Tags: objective-c, weekday

I looked all over and did not find a function that gives the number of business days between two dates.

How would I do that?

Of course it would not count the holidays, since each country has his own, but that I could do with some specific functions for my country.

EDIT: I did not ask how to get the number of days between two dates.

Comment: You didn't look hard enough as there are hundreds of solutions.

Comment: You mean the number of days between two dates, *excluding* the weekend days? Or what?

Comment: Popeye, i did found some solutions, but none was finished... I just wanted to know if there was any finished solution, but apparently there is not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So your definition of business days seems to be Mondays through Fridays.  Let's call these “workdays”, as opposed to “weekends” (which are Saturday and Sunday).

It is not obvious how to compute the number of workdays from a `startDate` to an `endDate`, so let's start with a simpler computation: the number of weeks from `startDate` to `endDate`.  By “week” I mean a seven day period starting on a Sunday.

If `startDate` and `endDate` fall in the same week, we'll count that week once.  If they fall in different weeks, we'll count the week containing `startDate`, the week containing `endDate`, and any weeks in between.  So this is an “inclusive” count of weeks.

Given this number of weeks, we can obviously multiply by 5 to get the number of workdays in the weeks.  But this isn't necessarily the number of workdays from `startDate` to `endDate`.  If `startDate` is a Sunday or a Monday, and `endDate` is a Saturday or a Sunday, then it's correct, but otherwise it counts some days that should be excluded.

How many days should be excluded?  First, consider `startDate`.  We need to exclude the number of workdays that precede `startDate` in the week (0 for Sunday and Monday, 1 for Tuesday, 2 for Wednesday, 3 for Thursday, 4 for Friday, and 5 for Saturday).  Then consider `endDate`.  We need to exclude the number of workdays that follow `endDate` in the week, and we need to exclude `endDate` itself if it is a workday (5 for Sunday and Monday, 4 for Tuesday, 3 for Wednesday, 2 for Thursday, 1 for Friday, and 0 for Saturday).

Given all that, the formula for the number of workdays from `startDate` to `endDate` is

```
 5 * inclusive count of weeks from startDate to endDate
   - count of workdays preceding startDate
   - count of workdays following and including endDate
```

This will, for example, give 1 if `startDate` is a Monday and `endDate` is the Tuesday of the same week.  If you would rather get 2 in that case (in other words, you want to count `endDate` as one of the workdays if it's not a weekend), then the formula is

```
 5 * inclusive count of weeks from startDate to endDate
   - count of workdays preceding startDate
   - count of workdays following (but not including) endDate
```

Now let's write it in Objective-C using Cocoa's excellent calendar computation support.  We'll implement this category on `NSCalendar`:

```
@interface NSCalendar (Rob_Workdays)

/** I return the number of non-weekend days from startDate to endDate,
    including the day containing `startDate` and excluding the day
    containing `endDate`. */
- (NSInteger)Rob_countOfWorkdaysFromDate:(NSDate *)startDate
    toDate:(NSDate *)endDate;

/** I return the number of non-weekend days from startDate to endDate,
    including the day containing `startDate` and the day containing
    `endDate`. */
- (NSInteger)Rob_countOfWorkdaysFromDate:(NSDate *)startDate
    toAndIncludingDate:(NSDate *)endDate;

@end
```

To implement those methods, let's translate the formulae directly into code:

```
@implementation NSCalendar (Rob_Workdays)

- (NSInteger)Rob_countOfWorkdaysFromDate:(NSDate *)startDate toDate:(NSDate *)endDate {
    return 5 * [self Rob_inclusiveCountOfWeeksFromDate:startDate toDate:endDate]
        - [self Rob_countOfWorkdaysPrecedingDate:startDate]
        - [self Rob_countOfWorkdaysFollowingAndIncludingDate:endDate];
}

- (NSInteger)Rob_countOfWorkdaysFromDate:(NSDate *)startDate toAndIncludingDate:(NSDate *)endDate {
    return 5 * [self Rob_inclusiveCountOfWeeksFromDate:startDate toDate:endDate]
        - [self Rob_countOfWorkdaysPrecedingDate:startDate]
        - [self Rob_countOfWorkdaysFollowingDate:endDate];
}
```

Of course we need to implement the helper methods, starting with the count of weeks.  To count weeks, we roll `startDate` backward until it's a Sunday, and we roll `endDate` forward until it's a Sunday.  Then we compute the number of days from `startDate` to `endDate` and divide by 7:

```
/** I return the number of weeks from `startDate` to `endDate`, including
    the weeks containing each date (but only counting the week once if the
    same week includes both dates). */
- (NSInteger)Rob_inclusiveCountOfWeeksFromDate:(NSDate *)startDate
    toDate:(NSDate *)endDate
{
    startDate = [self Rob_sundayOnOrBeforeDate:startDate];
    endDate = [self Rob_sundayAfterDate:endDate];
    NSDateComponents *components = [self components:NSCalendarUnitDay
        fromDate:startDate toDate:endDate options:0];
    return components.day / 7;
}
```

Here's how we roll back to a Sunday:

```
- (NSDate *)Rob_sundayOnOrBeforeDate:(NSDate *)date {
    return [self Rob_dateByAddingDays:1 - [self Rob_weekdayOfDate:date]
        toDate:date];
}
```

And here's how we roll forward to a Sunday:

```
- (NSDate *)Rob_sundayAfterDate:(NSDate *)date {
    return [self Rob_dateByAddingDays:8 - [self Rob_weekdayOfDate:date]
        toDate:date];
}
```

Here's how we compute the weekday (from 1=Sunday to 7=Saturday) of a date:

```
- (NSInteger)Rob_weekdayOfDate:(NSDate *)date {
    return [self components:NSCalendarUnitWeekday fromDate:date].weekday;
}
```

Here's how we add some number of days to a date:

```
- (NSDate *)Rob_dateByAddingDays:(NSInteger)days toDate:(NSDate *)date {
    if (days != 0) {
        NSDateComponents *components = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
        components.day = days;
        date = [self dateByAddingComponents:components toDate:date
            options:0];
    }
    return date;
}
```

Note that if `days` is negative, that method will roll the date back in time.

To compute the number of workdays preceding a date, we can either use brute force (since there are only seven days of the week to consider), which is easy to understand, or we can use a formula, which is smaller but harder to understand:

```
- (NSInteger)Rob_countOfWorkdaysPrecedingDate:(NSDate *)date {
    switch ([self Rob_weekdayOfDate:date]) {
        case 1: return 0;
        case 2: return 0;
        case 3: return 1;
        case 4: return 2;
        case 5: return 3;
        case 6: return 4;
        case 7: return 5;
        default: abort();
    }
    // equivalently: return MIN(MAX(0, [self Rob_weekdayOfDate:date] - 2), 5);
}
```

Computing the number of workdays following a date is similar, but we need two versions, depending on whether we're including or excluding the given date:

```
- (NSInteger)Rob_countOfWorkdaysFollowingAndIncludingDate:(NSDate *)date {
    switch ([self Rob_weekdayOfDate:date]) {
        case 1: return 5;
        case 2: return 5;
        case 3: return 4;
        case 4: return 3;
        case 5: return 2;
        case 6: return 1;
        case 7: return 0;
        default: abort();
    }
    // equivalently: return MIN(7 - [self Rob_weekdayOfDate:date], 5);
}

- (NSInteger)Rob_countOfWorkdaysFollowingDate:(NSDate *)date {
    switch ([self Rob_weekdayOfDate:date]) {
        case 1: return 5;
        case 2: return 4;
        case 3: return 3;
        case 4: return 2;
        case 5: return 1;
        case 6: return 0;
        case 7: return 0;
        default: abort();
    }
    // equivalently: return MAX(6 - [self Rob_weekdayOfDate:date], 0);
}

@end
```

Comment: You can also have an array of holiday dates and subtract them from the result if they are in the given interval :)

Comment: Thank you !
Did you write this or got from somewhere else ? i really did search a lot and couldn't find... Unfortunately i can't vote up, hehe. thx

Comment: I wrote it based on your question.  If it solves your problem, please click the check mark at the top of the answer to accept it.

Comment: @Sulthan, i've managed to subtract the holidays from the result by checking if the date is in the range, like you said... the function to check is the following:

+ (BOOL)date:(NSDate*)date isBetweenDate:(NSDate*)beginDate andDate:(NSDate*)endDate
{
    if ([date compare:beginDate] == NSOrderedAscending)
     return NO;
    
    if ([date compare:endDate] == NSOrderedDescending)
     return NO;
    
    return YES;
}